# Getting the SUM of total cost for each name

Tags: mysql, sql

> I'm trying to get the following result in mysql with below table: I
>   have tried to use `sum (case when)` but it give me the result for an
>   individual name only ,I want in the report the the total cost for each
>   user.

note: the ID column is not important you can ignore it .

```
mysql> select * from calls_records;

+----+-------+------------+------+
| id | month | name       | cost |
+----+-------+------------+------+
|  1 | 1     | osama      |   40 |
|  2 | 1     | rahman     |   40 |
|  3 | 1     | ahmed      |   30 |
|  4 | 1     | ali albann | 10.5 |
|  5 | 2     | osama      |   10 |
|  6 | 2     | ali albann |   30 |
|  7 | 2     | ahmed      |   10 |
|  8 | 2     | rahman     |   10 |
+----+-------+------------+------+
```

expected result

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| name       | total_cost_for_each_user  |
+------------+---------------------------+
| ahmed      |   50                      |
| ali albann | 40.5                      |
| osama      |   50                      |
| rahman     |   50                      |
+------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Try to `GROUP BY name`.

Comment: I tried that but it will not give you the total of cost for each user .

Comment: in your example where does id column come from. when you group it doesnt make sense to have this id..

Comment: Even month column in the expected output does not make sense

Comment: I have created this id column in the Database ,you may ignore it...I care only about (month,name,cost)

Comment: ok so in your example where does 50 come from for ahmed. i see only 30 in month one

Comment: the 50 or other value  is in the expected result it's possible to get 50 if we sum cost amount for the name ahmed or rahman .

Comment: only if you sum across multiple months ( actually still only sums to 40 ) and in this case it would make no sense to include month in the output column

Comment: Do you want to sum by both month and name or just by name?

Comment: I want to calculate the total cost for each name to be shown in the report

Comment: then please edit your expected output to contain only two columns name and total cost per name

Comment: SELECT name, sum(cost) as total_cost_for_each_user from calls_records group by name

Comment: Thanks @Harsh it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**query**

```
select name, sum(cost) as totalcost
from calls_records
group by name
;
```

**output**

```
+------------+-----------+
|    name    | totalcost |
+------------+-----------+
| ahmed      | 40        |
| ali albann | 40.5      |
| osama      | 50        |
| rahman     | 50        |
+------------+-----------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1da92b/4)